# Can't retrieve field from my model

Tags: django

I need to show fields title and text in separate text area in my template. I can't access them cause I am new in django here are my models.py

```
class Banner(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
text = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

and views.py

```
def home(request):

context = {}
return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

Comment: Which version you are using? Django 2.0+ uses __str__() while older versions uses __unicode__()

Comment: @DiegoVinícius no. That has nothing to do with versions of Django, but with Python.

Comment: ops true, my mistake, python 2.7 and python 3 hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import the model and use queryset to get all the data and then return it to view using render and use the pass content wherever you want in view

```
from .models import Banner

def home(request):
    queryset = Banner.objects.all()
    context = {
        'object_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

In you views html file you can use following:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your views is lack of information, you should import and call your objects

```
from .models import Banner

def home(request):
    context = {}
    context['banners'] =  Banner.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

In your html you can call

```
{% for banner in banners %}
    {{ banner.title }}
{% endfor %}
```